# Using HttpClient gives 'Script compilation failed' in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I've got a strange problem writing an Azure Function. I use HttpClient to get data from a webservice but when I run the function, I get a 'Script compilation failed'.
To isolate the problem, I've written an new Azure function in which I just retrieve a HTML response:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    CallHttpClient().Wait;
}

public static async Task CallHttpClient()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var str = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.google.com");
        log.Info(str);
    }
}
```

I'm using the Azure Portal. The Invocation log gives me this error:

Exception while executing function: Functions.TestFunctionAsync

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception
>   while executing function: Functions.TestFunctionAsync --->
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException : Script
>   compilation failed.    at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.CreateFunctionTarget(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 343    at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionLoader`1.GetFunctionTargetAsync[T](Int32
>   attemptCount) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\FunctionLoader.cs
>   : 0   at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.GetFunctionTargetAsync()
>   at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 192    at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[]
>   parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 260    at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[]
>   parameters) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\FunctionInvokerBase.cs
>   : 171    at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.InvokeAsync[TReflected](Object[]
>   arguments)    at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker
>   invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource
>   timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource
>   functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan
>   timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)    at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance
>   instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter
>   traceWriter,ILogger logger,CancellationTokenSou…

Comment: try adding `using System.Net;`

Comment: `using System.Net;` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Try calling `Wait` by adding the parens: `Wait()`

Comment: maybe you can salvage something from this example: https://github.com/4c74356b41/tryh4rder/blob/master/sharpito/run.csx

Comment: If `Run` supports async as in the example linked by @4c74356b41 then you should definitely `await` instead of `Wait()` so as to not block on async.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I've added parentheses to the `Wait` (was a typo in creating the isolated code) but this didn't work. I also made the `Run` method `async` and replaced the `.Wait()` with an `await`, but this also didn't made a difference.

Comment: Have you considered downloading VS2017 Update 3 Preview and installing [the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndrewBHall-MSFT.AzureFunctionToolsforVisualStudio2017) that lets you compile and run azure functions locally to test and see where the compilation error is (You must use VS2017 Update 3 to use the extension). Also in your last comment you did not mention adding `log` as a parameter like Mikhail's answer suggests.

Comment: Scott, my previous comment and Mikhail's answer were given at the same time. The issue is solved now. I know that the VS 2017 Preview supports Azure Functions but I didn't think it was necessary for a few simple lines of code. Think I have to reconsider...

Comment: I had this error with no explanation at all. After restart the Function App it worked fine. I didn't change anything on the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two compilation errors in your example: missing `()` after `Wait` and not passing `log` as parameter to `CallHttpClient`.

You shouldn't use `Wait()` at all, instead make `Run` async.

Here is a proper version:

```cs
public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    await CallHttpClient(log);
}

public static async Task CallHttpClient(TraceWriter log)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var str = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.google.com");
        log.Info(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not passing `log` was the problem. The function compiles now. I knew it should be something obvious...